# Where does views (map reduce) impact on CloudAnt NoSQL limits?

Tags: mapreduce, nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant

IBM Cloudant NoSQL has some limits on lookups,write,query per second.
[image]

On CloudAnt I can write a DesignDocument "View".

When I read a view, where does this read impact on? lookups/sec or query/sec?

For example this is the view:

```
function (doc) { 
   if(doc.DocType && doc.DocType=="car") {    
      emit(doc._id, {"brand":doc.brand, "model":doc.model});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "lookup" is something that hits Cloudant's primary key e.g. `GET /db/docid` or `GET /db/_all_docs`. A "query" is something that hits a secondary index, which includes:

- querying a Map/Reduce view
- querying a Cloudant Search (Lucene-based) index
- querying a Cloudant geo-spatial index
- querying a Cloudant Query index

In your example, reading back the results of a view would be classed as a "query" in billing terms

Comment: How could I manage the "very limiting limit" of 5 queries/sec?

Comment: You can set the reserved throughput capacity to match your needs, similar to other cloud platforms. Or is the question actually how you can get more capacity without paying for it? 

Note that a single query can return many documents and still only be counted a single query.